# Error in converting sql server 2005 database to sql server database 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to generate a script from sql 2005 database to sql 2000 database . After determining all the objects of database it is stopped and shows a message in error report that "Script failed for Server 'HOME\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)"

anyone can suggest me what should i do to convert sql 2005 to sql 2000 database

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SQL Server Database from 2005 to 2000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181363/convert-sql-server-database-from-2005-to-2000)

Comment: Sql 2000 doesn't know some keywords like in stored procedures of Sql 2005

Answer (score 1):

See [How to restore SQL 2005 DB to SQL 2000](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/46e3ecf9-6eab-4aa0-9453-11e7269efb6e/)